# Are the events E = "Draw a black card" and F = "Draw a 2, 3 or 4" independent?

Tags: probability

What I did:

P(E/F)=(6/52)/(12/52)=1/2=P(E)
Thus, they are independent.

Is this correct?

(The question is about a standard 52 card deck)

Comment: Ohh I see so they are in fact dependent? Edit: No no it was a mistake in my solution not the problem

Comment: Here is my new solution
P(E/F)=(6/52)/(12/52)=1/2=P(E)
Thus they are independent (but for different reasons). Is this now correct?

Comment: 12/52 is P(F). Because there are 4 2s, 3s, and 4s.

Comment: Sorry I am new to StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $P(E)=\frac{1}{2}$ , $P(F)=\frac{3}{13}$ and $P(E\cap F)=\frac{3}{26}$

So, $P(E)\times P(F)=\frac{3}{26}=P(E\cap F)$ , so $E$ and $F$ are independent.

Your new solution is also correct.